# What does the block argument to Array#first do?

Tags: ruby

My memory got the worst of me and I forgot about `Array#find`.

So I wrote some code which used `Array#first` to get the first item matching a condition:

```
first_even_num = [1,2,3].first { |x| x % 2 == 0 }
```

This does not work, it just returns the first element of the array no matter what the condition is. The block is not being called at all:

```
[1,2,3].first { |x| exit }
puts "the program did not exit"
```

I've accepted that `Array#first` does not do what imagined it to, but I'm curious why the aforementioned examples don't raise errors.

Looking at the [2.3.1](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-first) source, the only documented argument is an integer representing the number of returned results.

I don't really know C but this is what the underlying `Array#first` method has as a parameter signature:

```
rb_ary_first(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
```

I'm just wondering why the block provided to `Array#first` does not raise an error if it does nothing.

Comment: You can pass a block to _any_ method. It's up to the method to invoke it or check for its presence.

Comment: BTW, I pretty sure this has been ask before. Can anyone find the duplicate?

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, should've been asked and answered a number of times. Tried several queries, failed to produce a match. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass blocks to any method, absolutely any. If it doesn't need the block, it simply won't use it. It is not an error (because block is not one of the arguments. It's a separate input for a method)

Comment: And why does Ruby simply disregard the block? Because she does not know whether the method will yield to the block, which, for example, may depend on the result of conditional expressions. Moreover, there's no point for her to examine the built-in method [Array#first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-first), as any method may be modified at runtime.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: you think it's a she? :)

Comment: I guess if there's a [Boy Named "Sue"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZR5XGTpophI) there might be another named "Ruby", but...

Answer (score 2):

There's some simple rules about Ruby and blocks.

1. You can pass a block to any method.
2. That method may choose to run your block *zero or more times* at any point in time from the present to the distant future.
3. You must read the documentation or method implementation to understand if, how and when a block will be exercised. There is no other way of knowing.

Your example here of passing a block to a method that's not expecting one is consistent with these rules. Effectively it's being run zero times and has no bearing on the outcome of the `first` call.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the result by doing some thing like below.

```
def get_first_even(arr)
if arr.first % 2 == 0
    first_even_num = arr.first
    puts first_even_num
else
    arr.delete_at 0
    get_first_even arr
end
end

get_first_even [1,3,5,7,9,23,13,14,11,12]
```